# Is there a ‘correct’ way to store maven test commands?

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I come from a JavaScript background so getting my head round some Java particulars.

I’m using selenium and Java with Maven as my framework.

In JS we’d have scripts within the package.json for example

```
Test-local
Test-headless
```

These scripts would point to a config file that contained the chromedriver options etc etc.

I know I can’t do that in Java selenium.

Am I best placed creating classes that contain the difference between local runs/headless runs/docker runs

And then calling the command like

```
mvn test -Dtest=fully.qualified.package.ClassName
```

Or is there some other way I’ve totally missed?

Thanks

Comment: What's going to be the difference between 2 configurations - sounds like it's just about different params that need to be passed to Selenium?

Comment: Yeah mostly params, cucumber options, driver options etc

Comment: So you just need to pass params to the code that initializes all of that. And the code is going to be shared across all the tests, right? If you use surefire plugin to start tests (would be used in case of JUnit/TestNG) the way to pass options is through `<configuration><argLine>...</argLine></configuration>`. BTW, how far are you in writing those tests? Do you already have a lot of those?

Comment: I’ve got surefire installed ! I’ve three tests but I’m more concerned about getting my framework in order before expanding coverage. And yeah all tests when running locally will use the same arguments

Comment: The docker one will contain a few more steps as I need to build the container and then run the command in the container. 

I could also have shell scripts and use Executions on the maven plug-in in the POM. But again it’s the what’s the “correct” way. What’s the standard most follow?

Comment: Ok.. Since you're not far from the start yet, maybe you could reconsider your stack, so I'll just comment here and you feel free to ignore. First, Cucumber and any other given-when-then frameworks are too cumbersome, and I don't think there are many who still use them. I'd use JUnit instead. Then.. Google has been developing Puppeteer for in-browser testing, and then Microsoft lured away the team and now developing Playwright, I'm not sure if it makes sense to keep using Selenium.

Comment: As for the Docker - it probably makes sense to run mvn inside Docker. But I'm not sure what you want to do with it, so I'll also mention Testcontainers - it's a way to start a docker container from Java. Used e.g. when you want to start a DB and run tests against that DB.

Comment: Unfortunately I’m going to have to stay in selenium as it’s a QA repo. I’m tasked with moving all tests which are in selenium to a more robust and “standard” way of working. Which is why I’m defining lots of correct ways, adding linters etc. Then I’ll pull across the tests into the new framework which has been setup correctly

Comment: The docker will be used as I want to schedule the tests to run automatically. I don’t want them running on my local PC, they’ll probably run at night in a docker container, which is hosted on aws or something then spun back down. So I’ve results in the morning

Comment: Ah, for scheduling jobs remotely you can take a look at CI servers/services like GitHub Actions, Jenkins, etc. Those will give you an ability to schedule, run manually, run on a push to the repository, and then can also visualize/see the details from within browser.

Comment: Yeah it’s currently set to run via Jenkins albeit locally for now until i get it running on a hosted docker container.

Comment: If you set up a remote Jenkins, you won't have to bother running the tests in a container - Jenkins is capable of installing Java and Maven on its own. Jenkins itself however can run in a container if needed..